# How to modify the `core_pattern` when building docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to modify the `core_pattern` when building docker image, and my docker file is like this:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN echo "core-%e" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Then I ran `docker build` and I get an error

```
/bin/sh: /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern: Read-only file system
```

Anybody help?

Comment: Writing to `procfs` during the build process is fairly useless, as this affects only the running kernel and will not be stored in the image, thus, will not affect consequent container runs. You need to have some script or program which does this during the container startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed this myself, I just found out how.
it is not related to docker, but to linux in general.
I am using ubuntu and I am 99% certain centos will behave the same in this regard.

it is edited via `sysctl` command.

see example

```
bash$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
bash$ sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern="|/usr/share/apport/apport-kde %p %s %c %d %P %E"
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/share/apport/apport-kde %p %s %c %d %P %E
bash$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
|/usr/share/apport/apport-kde %p %s %c %d %P %E
bash$
```

note that value starting with `|` is to express commands. the core dump will be sent to the command as STDIN

Since you asked your question about docker, let me also provide a compatible answer.

```
FROM centos:7
RUN sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern="core-%e"
```

for more info on the core pattern you can use in your file, instead of just %e, see https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/

also another related question/answer that has more details

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343275/why-is-editing-core-pattern-restricted

Comment: Thank you. And I found another way. Add `echo "core-%e" | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern &> /dev/null` into the `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: The RUN step in this answer gives the same `Read-only file system` error as in the original question, because `/proc/sys` cannot be modified by unprivileged containers. So, unless I'm missing something huge, I think this answer should not be accepted.

Comment: @jacquev6 it works for me, if you cannot execute `sudo sysctl xyz` then I believe you have a different problem not covered by this question or my answer.

Comment: Weird, it's the first time I encounter a "It works for me" situation using Docker. `sudo sysctl` works on the host, but when building the Dockerfile in this answer (without the `sudo`, because in the `centos:7` image the default user is already `root`), I get that "read-only" error. @MathieuJ. can you confirm you ran `docker build .` and it worked?

Comment: Also see [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5703#issuecomment-42702024) stating that they "restricted access to /proc and /sys. In order to deal with those, you need to be in privileged mode. It is not possible to run privileged build step."

Comment: @jacquev6 yes, but not with centos:7, the base image was different. so that would explain the difference.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to have different core_pattern in the host and in the container at the same time, as docker is sharing the kernel with its host.
However, you can run the container in privileged mode and change core_pattern from inside a container during startup/runtime (modify core_pattern in CMD section or execute os command from inside).
But keep in mind that this setting will not be automatically restored after the container finished (until you do it programmatically).

Answer (score 2):

If you run it in a container, using '--privileged' option in run cmd.

```
docker run --privileged <the docker image ID>
```

Then run in container:

```
sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
```

Here is my example:

```
ylin30@yi-IdeaPad:~/TS-Benchmark/tsdb-test$ sudo docker run -d --privileged --name ticktock -h ticktock -p 6182:6182 -p 6181:6181 --cpus="1" -m 4g ytyou/ticktock:latest --tsdb.timestamp.resolution millisecond --tcp.buffer.size 3mb
7078cfa224eadcfa76a0a6938214f99b17f9d295fc581580a63fdc4dc3185874
ylin30@yi-IdeaPad:~/TS-Benchmark/tsdb-test$ sudo docker exec -u 0 -it ticktock /bin/bash
root@ticktock:/tmp# sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
root@ticktock:/tmp# sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
kernel.core_pattern = /tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
root@ticktock:/tmp# sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = /tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
root@ticktock:/tmp#
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way. Add echo "core-%e" | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern &> /dev/null into the ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

when using docker, those files are protected that you can't change anyway, even using `sudo sysctl` to write. (At least in my situation).

so you need to run docker cmd in your local terminal like this (in your case):

```
docker run --privileged <the docker image ID> sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core-%e
```

after you connect to this image, you will find the core pattern has changed.