# What's the Kubernetes equivalent to docker --privileged?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I wanted to host a TDengine cluster in Kubernetes, then met an error when I enabled coredump in the container.

I've searched Stack Overflow and found the Docker solution, [How to modify the `core_pattern` when building docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574458/how-to-modify-the-core-pattern-when-building-docker-image), but not the Kubernetes one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  template: 
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: my-image
        name: my-app
        ...
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          runAsUser: 0
```

Comment: Hello @zitsen Did this answer help you?
If no, could you please provide more details in your question - in which container you got an error, text of this error?

Comment: Already worked, thanks for your help. appologize for late response.

Answer (score 0):

Just some fix to the picked answer, the final worked yaml is:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: core
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: core
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: core
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: zitsen/enable-coredump:0.1.0
          name: core
          command: ["/bin/sleep", "3650d"]
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            runAsUser: 0
```